# ASPNET Core - Page model not getting constructed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an aspnet core app. My IndexModel constructor never gets called and when I run the page I get:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Pages_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+
    History Items: @Model.HistoryItems.Count
```

If I run it without referencing the model, the page comes up, but the Model constructor never gets called.

My **HomeController** is simply:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My **Index.cshtml** (in */Pages/Home*) is:

```
@using MyApp.PageModels
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyApp";
}
<div class="overflow-hidden w-full h-full relative">
    History Items: @Model.HistoryItems.Count
</div>
```

My **Index.cshtml.cs** (also in */Pages/Home*) is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using MyApp.PageModels;

namespace MyApp.Pages.Home;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel()
    {
    }

    public List<HistoryItem> HistoryItems { get; } = new List<HistoryItem>()
    {
        new HistoryItem() { ConversationId = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "History Item 1" },
        new HistoryItem() { ConversationId = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "History Item 2" },
        new HistoryItem() { ConversationId = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "History Item 3" },
        new HistoryItem() { ConversationId = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "History Item 4" }
    };
    
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

In my **Program.cs** I have:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "account",
        pattern: "Account/{action=Login}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

and elsewhere:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Account/{0}.cshtml");
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
});

services.AddRazorPages(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Pages");
```

I've tried a bunch of things and I can't seem to get past this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass model directly to the view, like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new IndexModel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel stupid. Haven't done front-end stuff in a # of years.

Comment: Glad I could help! Btw what you are doing here is weird, you should not inherit your model from PageModel, you are mixing RazorPages with MVC

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix it. I've been using ChatGPT to help generate some of the code and it frequently gets them confused in the code it returns to me. It's even mixed in Blazor code a couple of times...

Comment: Good luck with it then!